# Why instead of two different AsyncTasks one executes two times?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I have code where I send request to the server and get the response. Response depends  on the set of parameters which I send to the server.But because of some reason I got the same result.Here is a code: I call `sendDashboardRequest` for two different set of parameters:

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, Object> serverParameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
serverParameters.put("user_id", result.get("user_id"));
serverParameters.put("limit", Integer.valueOf(1000).toString());
serverParameters.put("type", Integer.valueOf(1).toString());
sendDashboardRequest(serverParameters);
 serverParameters.put("type", Integer.valueOf(2).toString());
sendDashboardRequest(serverParameters);//Executes only this AsyncTask twice!
```

And here is code of the method `sendDashboardRequest` which starts new AsyncTasks:

```
public void sendDashboardRequest(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> params) {

    new AsyncTask<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>, Void, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>()
    {    
         NetworkOp lowLevelOps = new NetworkOp();
        @Override
        protected LinkedHashMap<String, Object> doInBackground (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>... params)    
       { 

        return  lowLevelOps.executeCommand(DASHBOARD_COMMAND, params[0]);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result)
        {   
                        //And here I gave the same result!But parameters which I send to the server are different!
        }
    }.execute(params);
}
```

The most interesting thing is when I create two different methods with same body and call each for the different set of parameters everything works well and two different AsyncTasks starts.

Comment: sendDashboardRequest is async. serverParameters is modified after sendDashboardRequest returns, but before the asynctask is executed. Solution : create a different map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending the same `LinkedHashMap` in both requests. Since the requests are serviced in a background thread, the timing will be unpredictable and you can't guarantee that the background thread for the first request will execute before you issue the second request. In this case, by chance, the modified value in the second request is already in the map by the time the first request gets executed.

You should use a different map for each request, or else change `sendDashboardRequest` so that it copies the data it needs rather than relying on the passed-in map remaining constant.

Comment: Thanks.But can you explain in more details this phrase: " Since the requests are serviced in a background thread, the modified value in the second request is already in the map by the time the first request gets executed."? I'm new to Android.

Comment: You are issuing two requests in quick succession, and the second request (with the modified data) is sent before the first one has even started executing.